# How to convert binary float to decimal float

Tags: functions

I need to convert binary float to decimal float in Mathematica, ideally between any two bases.

`FromDigits["1.111111", 2]` does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to get the `RealDigits` first:

```
FromDigits[RealDigits[1.111111], 2]
```

This gives (after `N`) `1.98438` which matches the value solved for [here](http://www.digitconvert.com/).

If you want to work between any two bases, say you wanted to know how to write the number 18 in hex:

```
FromDigits[RealDigits[18, 16]]

(* Out[]:= 12 *)
```

Alternatively, if you just want to "know" what the number is, without needing to compute with it, you can use `BaseForm`:

```
BaseForm[18, 16]
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you are looking for this may help:

```
FromDigits[{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 1}, 2]

(*
=> 1.984,,,,
*)
```

The format given as input to `FromDigits` is seen in the Documentation for `RealDigits`.

Answer (score 2):

To convert a real number in base less than 10 to base 10, you can use Eli's method. However, suppose you want to convert the number `a1.34dc` in base 16 to base 10, then Eli's method doesn't work anymore. One workaround is to extract the decimal point from the string representing the number, convert the string using `FromDigits` and multiply by an appropriate factor, e.g.

```
realTransform[str_String, b0_] := Module[{p, int, digits},
  p = StringPosition[str, ".", 1];
  int = FromDigits[
    If[Length[p] == 1, StringDrop[str, p[[1, {1}]]], str], b0];
  If[Length[p] > 0, int = N@int/b0^(StringLength[str] - p[[1, 1]])];
  int]

realTransform["ab.bcf", 16]

(* ==> 171.738 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the other good answers. If you aren't looking for anything programatic, the following may help.

As to inputting a number in any base, you can type `base^^number`.

So, for example, `2^^1.111111` returns `1.98438`.

If you want to see a number's representation in another base you can use, e.g,  `BaseForm[2^^1.111, 4]`